# Writing Python code to create intersection loop with geodatabase?

Tags: arcpy, intersection

I am trying create a loop that will intersect each individual township with a statewide section layer. I am having trouble with the syntax of the intersect tool I think, but maybe it is something else.

```
# Import system modules
import sys, string, os, arcgisscripting
import arcpy, os, sys, string
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

arcpy.OverWriteOutput = 1
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


input_folder = "C:\\state\\towns.gdb"
arcpy.env.workspace = input_folder
out_wksp = "C:\\state\\township_sections.gdb\\"

env.workspace = input_folder

fcl = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
print fcl

infeatures = ["C:\\state\\towns.gdb\\sections", fcl]
print infeatures


#ExtractByMask_sa (in_raster, in_mask_data, out_raster) 
for fc in input_folder:
    print fc
    arcpy.Intersect_analysis(infeatures, out_wksp + fcl, "ALL", "", "INPUT")
    #arcpy.Intersect_analysis(["C:\\state\\towns.gdb\\sections" fcl], out_wksp + fcl, "ALL", "", "INPUT")
#    fc = fclist.Next()
    print 'clipped', fcl

print 'done'
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. out_wksp + fcl doesn't look right. fcl is all the feature layers, surely it should be out_wksp  + fc. Your iteration does't look right either. Are you trying to do each feature class in a database and/or some shapefiles too?

Answer (score 3):

It is apparent that you are using a 9/9.3 example that clipped rasters. Here's a markup to show you the difference:

```
# Import system modules
# import sys, string, os, arcgisscripting #9/9.3 geoprocessor, use arcpy instead
import arcpy, os, sys, string
from arcpy import env
#from arcpy.sa import * # don't need this, you're not doing any Spatial Analyst functions
#gp = arcgisscripting.create()#9/9.3 geoprocessor, use arcpy instead

# arcpy.OverWriteOutput = 1 this is (sort of) the Old way
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True # this is right

input_folder = "C:\\state\\towns.gdb"
arcpy.env.workspace = input_folder # this is right
out_wksp = "C:\\state\\township_sections.gdb\\"

#env.workspace = input_folder # not right, already done

fcl = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
print fcl

infeatures = ["C:\\state\\towns.gdb\\sections", fcl] # not sure what this is about??
print infeatures

for fc in fcl:
    print fc
    infeatures = input_folder + '\\' + fc
    arcpy.Intersect_analysis(infeatures, out_wksp + fc, "ALL", "", "INPUT")
    print 'clipped ' + fc

print 'done'
```

When iterating feature classes you get a list using `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()` and then iterate using `for fc in the_list:` where essentially `fc` is a string with the name of each feature class. For safety use the full path name, just in case you've changed your workspace along the way: `infeatures = input_folder + '\\' + fc`.

You've imported env from arcpy so you don't need to `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput` it could be `env.overwriteOutput` it doesn't make any difference at runtime but there's no point `from arcpy import env` if you intend to fully qualify it later... that's just me being picky though.